# How to iterate two list of WebElements and print the values one by one to perform some action

Tags: selenium-webdriver, elements

As you can see I Have two list and I want output like one from one list and second from second list following is my code please help me in this.

### Code in Selenium Webdriver in Java:

```java
@Test
public void firstcase() {

    List<WebElement> elements = dr.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='job-card__subtitle hidden-xs']//span"));
    System.out.println("Company name:" + elements.size());

    List<WebElement> Jobelements = dr.findElements(By.xpath("(//div[contains(@class,'job-card__title title-overflow')])"));
    System.out.println("Profile:-" + Jobelements.size());

    for (WebElement temp : elements) {
        System.out.println("Company name:" +temp.getText());

    }

    for (WebElement tempjob : Jobelements) {
        System.out.println("Profile:-" +tempjob.getText());

    }
}
```

---

```
my output is:=
Company name:-6
Profile:-6
Company name:-Canon
Company name:-Reliance Automation
Company name:-Alibaba
Company name:-Kodak
Company name:-Vodafone
Company name:-PeopleGrove
Profile:-Market Researcher
Profile:-Program Manager
Profile:-Developer
Profile:-Market Researcher
Profile:-Sales Representative
Profile:-Customer Support Specialist
```

[image: I want Output like Company name:Canon new line Profile:-Market Researcher]

Answer (score 1):

```
@Test
    public void firstcase() {

        List<WebElement> elements = dr.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='job-card__subtitle hidden-xs']//span"));
        System.out.println("Company name:" + elements.size());

        List<WebElement> Jobelements = dr.findElements(By.xpath("(//div[contains(@class,'job-card__title title-overflow')])"));
        System.out.println("Profile:-" + Jobelements.size());


        for (i=0;i<elements.size();++i) {
            System.out.println("Profile:-" +Jobelements.get(I).getText());
            System.out.println("Company name:-" +elements.get(I).getText());

        }

    }
```

Just iterate through size

Comment: Thank you for your help but it's showing error when i am adding for loop and error is the type of the type of the expression must be array type but it resolved to List <WebElement>

Comment: Which line shows that error

Comment: @Jitendra updated the answer instead of [i] use get(I)

Comment: You can use [I] only for simple array for list interface you should use get(I) to get the balue

Comment: Just because of your help i got my answer which i want. Thank You for help...

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();
cars.add("Volvo");
cars.add("BMW");
cars.add("Ford");
cars.add("Mazda");

ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
numbers.add(12);
numbers.add(13);
numbers.add(14);
numbers.add(15);


// Get the iterator
Iterator<String> it = cars.iterator();

Iterator<Integer> it1 = numbers.iterator();

while(it.hasNext()){

System.out.println(it.next());

if(it1.hasNext())

System.out.println(it1.next());

}
```

**Results** are:

```
Volvo
12
BMW
13
Ford
14
Mazda
15
```

Comment: why to add that much extraline of code?